# Android won't scroll https iframe

Tags: android, iframe, https, scroll

On Android using any **https** iframe src that is out of domain results in the iframe not scrolling:

```
<div style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
    height:300px;width:300px;overflow:auto;">
<iframe height="100%" src="https://fully-qualified-domain/"></iframe>
</div>
```

Is there a way to have the iframe expand naturally based on its content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution I've found so far is to set a min-height on the iframe that seems suitable for the content. If it's too large then the iframe scrolls a long time and it's a little cumbersome to use, but at least it makes it possible to see the iframed page.

```
<div style="-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
   height:300px;width:300px;overflow:auto;">
<iframe style="min-height:1000px;" height="100%" src="https://fully-qualified-domain/"></iframe>
</div>
```